# while getting null value in datareader getting error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have an If clause like this:

```
If pkgBasedOn = "Area" Then
                        sql = "select F_Pkg from dbo.T_Exhibitor Where  [F_Exhibitor_Code] = '" & cmb_Exhibitor.SelectedValue.ToString & "'"
                        cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
                        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

                        If dr.Read Then
                            pkgCount = IIf(dr(0).ToString() = "", "", dr(0).ToString())
                        End If
                        dr.Close()
                    Else
                        pkgCount = 1
                    End If
```

Whenever the F_Pkg value is null, I get the following error:

"conversion from string "" to type integer is not valid"

Comment: if `pkgcount` is a numeric, why are you trying to set it to a string value? also, a) use SQL parameters, not string concat; b) use `If()` rather than `IIF` c) you should check for rows returned (`dr,HasRows`) and d) dispose of DB object when done with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't this this error is because of `null` because `null.ToString()` will give you `""` but how can you assign `""` to an `integer`? so you should need to do some conversion for this.

```
 pkgCount =Val(IIf(dr(0).ToString() = "", "", dr(0).ToString()))
```

So you will get `0` if the string is `""`

Comment: yes..sir ..its worked fine for me..thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

First ,

```
If dr.Read Then
                        pkgCount = IIf(dr(0).ToString() = "", "",   dr(0).ToString())
else
     //print an error message like ' No item found!!' or something up to your wish


                    End If
```

Then, Surround  with try catch so as to catch error

```
try{

//your code

}

catch(Exception e){
   e.getmessage();
}
```